# My mouse is lighting but it doesn't move

Tags: windows, mouse

When my PC opens it works pretty fine but later it stops moving. I have to restart my PC every time in order for it to work.

Comment: What did you tried till now? Did you try to unplug and plug it again? 
Please [edit] your question adding some info about your OS, the version, and maybe the model of the mouse. Did you try with another mouse? ... ah last suggestion It Is Not Needed To Capitalize Each Word. `;-)`

Comment: **P**lease **D**on't **W**rite **I**n **A**ll **T**itle **C**ase, unless it really ***is*** a book title. Makes it painful to try to read  :/

Comment: Yes, difficult to advice, if not knowing some essential details, desktop/laptop, regular/wireless/laptop mouse, OS etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Change your mouse.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/8-things-know-replace-crappy-10-mouse/) Please, just do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not...

1) Try using it on another PC
2) Try using another mouse on your PC

this will tell you if its the mouse, or the PC

If its the PC:
Could be a virus or other program taking control of the mouse.
It could be a failing port, if its a USB mouse, you could try to use another port, but you have probably already tried that.

If its the mouse:
Change it, it probably is some kind of problem with the sensors or cable or other. It would be best to change it, those are not so expensive, usually.